# unable to upload iOS app to fabric using fastlane

Tags: ios, crashlytics, fabric.io, crashlytics-beta

I am trying to upload a new iOS app to Fabric using the fastlane crashlytics action by providing the API and secret. When I run the fastlane command, it does build, archive the app successfully and when it starts uploading to Crashlytics Beta (fabric), it fails with the below message:

```
INFO [2018-06-12 11:06:52.74]: --- Step: crashlytics ---
INFO [2018-06-12 11:06:52.74]: -------------------------
INFO [2018-06-12 11:06:52.74]: Uploading the build to Crashlytics Beta. Time     
for some ☕️.
DEBUG [2018-06-12 11:06:52.74]: ./Pods/Crashlytics/submit [[API_TOKEN]]         
[[BUILD_SECRET]] -ipaPath './archives/Newton.Beta-1.0.0-1337.ipa' -groupAliases 
'mobile-team,ios-test-devices' -notifications YES -debug YES
ERROR [2018-06-12 11:06:57.99]: Shell command exited with exit status 1 instead 
of 0.
WARN [2018-06-12 11:06:58.00]: Lane Context:
INFO [2018-06-12 11:06:58.00]: {:DEFAULT_PLATFORM=>:ios, :PLATFORM_NAME=>nil, 
:LANE_NAME=>"beta", :GIT_REPO_WAS_CLEAN_ON_START=>true, 
:VERSION_NUMBER=>"1.0.0", :BUILD_NUMBER=>"1337", 
:IPA_OUTPUT_PATH=>"/Users/sanjaneya/Documents/newton-ios/archives/Newton.Beta- 
1.0.0-1337.ipa", 
:XCODEBUILD_ARCHIVE=>"/Users/sanjaneya/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018- 
06-12/Newton.Beta-1.0.0-1337 2018-06-12 10.57.07.xcarchive"}
ERROR [2018-06-12 11:06:58.00]: 2018-06-12 11:06:53.605 submit Crashlytics: 
Crashlytics.framework/submit 1.3.5 (18)
2018-06-12 11:06:53.613 submit Crashlytics: Path to IPA manually provided: 
./archives/Newton.Beta-1.0.0-1337.ipa
2018-06-12 11:06:54.154 submit Crashlytics: Path To App: 
/var/folders/nc/x2sh_3t17692n9jf3pybxt2n8c1sfm/T/Newton.Beta-1.0.0- 
1337/Payload/Newton.app
2018-06-12 11:06:57.943 submit Crashlytics: Unable to add testers: Project beta 
is inactive
2018-06-12 11:06:57.943 submit Crashlytics: Failed to add testers/groups to the 
release
```

I did try to follow the recommendations from other stack overflow articles but could not figure out the resolution:

1. Added the fabric run command to Build Phases as run script in Xcode
2. Cleaned, built the app and also did Run the app successfully in simulator.

Even after above two steps, I do not see the app in the Fabric Dashboard. Please help!

Comment: Thanks. Please reach out to the Fabric team with your bundle ID or package name.